# PHP - Don't load the page if exception is caught

Tags: php, class, exception, methods

I'm new to OO PHP...I'm trying to create a PHP class called `MyClass` and some methods that should:

1. validate that parameters are numeric
2. validate that parameters are defined
3. if any of the above fail I need to send an exception with explanation

When I call the `MyFunction` method like this:

```
$quotation = new Quotations\MyClass(); 
echo $quotationResult = $quotation -> MyFunction('A', 'B', 2, 'a');
```

to test if it will throw an exception but for some reason page doesn't load saying - "localhost is currently unable to handle this request". But when I call it like this:

```
$quotation = new Quotations\MyClass(); 
echo $quotationResult = $quotation -> MyFunction('A', 'B', 2, 3);
```

it works fine (I can see blank page).

Why it doesn't allow me to print an exception in the browser?

My script:

```
<?php

namespace Quotations;

class MyClass {

var $is_number;
var $is_defined;
private $number;
private $defined;

private function isNumeric($w, $c){
    if(is_numeric($w) && is_numeric($c)){
        $number = true;
    }
    else{
        $number = false;
    }

    return $number;
}

private function isDefined($t, $f, $w, $c){
    if(isset($t, $f, $w, $c)){
        $defined = true;
    }
    else{
        $defined = false;
    }

    return $defined;
}

function MyFunction($to, $from, $weight, $cube) {
    try{
        if(!$this -> isNumeric($weight, $cube)){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Arguments are not numeric');
        }

        if(!$this -> isDefined($to, $from, $weight, $cube)){
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Arguments are missing');
        }
    }catch(InvalidArgumentException $e){
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }catch(BadMethodCallException $e){
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    } 
}
 }
?>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing brace for your MyClass declaration, so it should always fail as a syntax error. Enable error reporting to ensure you see PHP's error output

Comment: Thanks, I've added that brace but still the same output!

Comment: Don't edit the solution into the question. Post it as an answer. That way, people can see what the original problem was and how it differs from the solution.

Comment: @Barmar, if you would like you could post the right answer and I will mark it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backslashes before the execption names to look for them in the global namespace. Otherwise, it looks for them in the `Quotations` namespace.

```
function MyFunction($to, $from, $weight, $cube) {
    try {
        if(!$this -> isNumeric($weight, $cube)){
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Arguments are not numeric');
        }

        if(!$this -> isDefined($to, $from, $weight, $cube)){
            throw new \BadMethodCallException('Arguments are missing');
        }
    } catch(\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    } catch(\BadMethodCallException $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First step is to enable error reporting - 

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

`ini_set("display_errors", 1);`.

From looking at your code you seem to be missing a closing bracket your code should look like this.

```
namespace Quotations;

class MyClass {
    var $is_number;
    var $is_defined;
    private $number;
    private $defined;

    private function isNumeric($w, $c) {
        if(is_numeric($w) && is_numeric($c)){
            $number = true;
        }
        else {
            $number = false;
        }

        return $number;
    }

    private function isDefined($t, $f, $w, $c){
        if( isset( $t, $f, $w, $c ) ){
            $defined = true;
        }
        else {
            $defined = false;
        }

        return $defined;
    }

    function MyFunction($to, $from, $weight, $cube) {
        try {
            if(!$this -> isNumeric($weight, $cube)){
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Arguments are not numeric');
            }

            if(!$this -> isDefined($to, $from, $weight, $cube)){
                throw new BadMethodCallException('Arguments are missing');
            }
        } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        } catch(BadMethodCallException $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        } 
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I saw you said in the comments you have added the `}` and still no luck so I looked through your code and found the following problem

So this is my last solutions I can think of xD

```
function MyFunction( $to, $from, $weight, $cube ) {
    try
    {
        try
        {
            if( !$this->isNumeric( $weight, $cube ) ) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException( 'Arguments are not numeric' );
            }
        } catch ( \InvalidArgumentException $e ) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        try
        {
            if( !$this->isDefined( $to, $from, $weight, $cube ) ){
                throw new \BadMethodCallException( 'Arguments are missing' );
            }
        } catch ( \BadMethodCallException $e ) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This kind of error I've got - Fatal error: Class Quotations\BadMethodCallException not found

Comment: Try removing the `isDefined` from your code and try again

Comment: @DenissMuntjans Try using `\BadMethodCallException` so it will look in the global namespace.

Comment: It works fine (I can see blank page) but I'm trying to see will it throw an exception is I specify the $cube parameter as a string rather than number and I would like to see an exception message in my browser rather than - localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: Ah I'm updating my answer

Comment: @Barmar you might be right but now I'm getting this error - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Arguments are not numeric' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/CM/class/MyClass.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/CM/test.php(20): Quotations\MyClass->MyFunction('A', 'B', 2, 'a') #1 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/CM/class/MyClass.php on line 52

Comment: Put the backslash in the `catch()` clauses as well.

Comment: @CoderSte `error_reporting()` and `ini_set()` can't help with reporting syntax errors. If there's a syntax error, none of the code runs, so it never calls those functions.

Comment: @Barmar, by the way I just noticed that when I remove any of the last 2 parameters and call function like this - `MyFunction('A', 'B', 2)` it saying - `Arguments are not numeric` rather that `Arguments are missing`. Is it possible to change that somehow?

Comment: Change the order of your `if` tests, so you check for missing arguments first.

Comment: Thanks you so much!